# How to fix "ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io" error while using Docker?

Tags: docker, virtualization, containers

I am compiling sources of one cosmos-based blockchain projects on my MacOS. This project using Docker. I installed Docker and it seems running properly. But at the and of compiling I got this message related to Docker:

```
[+] Building 0.3s (2/3)                                                                                                                       
[+] Building 0.4s (3/3) FINISHED                                                                                                              
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
 => => transferring dockerfile: 719B             
 => [internal] load .dockerignore   
 => => transferring context: 2B   
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/golang:1.20.1-alpine3.17 
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/golang:1.20.1-alpine3.17:
------
Dockerfile:1
--------------------
   1 | >>> FROM golang:1.20.1-alpine3.17
   2 |     
   3 |     WORKDIR /
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: error getting credentials - err: exit status 1, out: ``
```

Can someone help me to find a solution to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Try removing `"credsStore": "desktop.exe"`, from `~/.docker/config.json` as suggested here https://github.com/docker/buildx/issues/476 .
I was having an issue on `FROM php:7.4-apache` with the same error message, and the credsStore fix worked for me.

Edit:
`"credsStore": "desktop"` on mac

Comment: worked for me too:

macOS 13.5.1 (22G90) Ventura
docker desktop 4.21.1 (114176)

Comment: It worked for me too

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue which I was getting when I run docker build command on my MAC by adding --platform="linux/amd64" at the end of the command.

Comment: This worked for me. Building an linux/amd64 image on an M1 Mac.